# Javascript autoplaying images, in random order with links

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a series of images autoplay on a website via Javascript (where the order/sequence it plays back is random every time). I am also trying to make some of these images have hyperlinks in them that redirect to different sites.

My understanding of JS is very limited. I have been scouring the web for different approaches and methods to get to where I am, but the JS I've come up with fails to work.

This is what I currently have:

```
var imgLinks = [
// format: ['imageSource','imageLinkURL'],
  ['1.jpg','https://example.com'],
  ['2.jpg','https://www.google.com'],
  ['3.jpg','https://www.yahoo.com'],
  ['4.jpg','https://www.bing.com'],
  ['5.jpg','https://ddg.gg']
  // NOTE: no comma after last entry
];


function displayImage(){
  var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * (imagesArray.length));
  if (!usedImages[num]){
    document.canvas.src = imagesArray[num];
    usedImages[num] = true;
    usedImagesCount++;
    if (usedImagesCount === imagesArray.length){
        usedImagesCount = 0;
        usedImages = {};
    }
  } else {
    displayImage();
  }
}
window.onload = function() {
  setInterval(changeBanner, 300)

  function GoToURL(URL) {
    document.location.href = URL; 
  }

  onload = function () {
    RandomLink();
  }
};
```

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: You haven't defined the *RandomLink* function anywhere, and you've assigned the function calling it to a global *onload* property after the document has loaded, so it's too late to be called anyway. The *GoToURL* function isn't called in the onload listener and can't be called otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this function:

```
function RandomLink(arr){
  var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);
  return arr[index];
}
```

with `arr` is your `imgLinks`

Please check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/71arv4n3/5/)